# How to disable modal error message on jqgrid loadError call on page reload

Tags: ajax, jquery, jqgrid

JqGrid 4.4.5 is populated using remote json data.
jqGrid loadError method is defined as

```
loadError: function LoadErrorHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert('Load error ' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + '\n status ' + textStatus +
                  '\n error ' + errorThrown);
  }
```

If browser refresh button in page is pressed rapidly or F5 key is hold down in Chrome modal alert box defined in method appears.

How to disable this alert box in Chrome ?
Is is possible to dedect that page is in reload state and not to show this box or other idea ?

In FireFox alert box only flashes and in IE 10 it does not occur. It looks like this is issue in Chrome only.

Passed parameter values are in this case:

```
jqXHR: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"} 
textStatus:  error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to write advices about the case which can't be clear reproduced.

Probably you use virtual scrolling and have some effects existing only in the case? If it is so you can try repeat the same test without usage of `scroll: 1` or `scroll: true`.

Another reason could be that some web browsers calls `abort` method of `jqXHR`. I would recommend you to test the code with different versions of jQuery. Mostly one have `textStatus === "abort"` or `errorThrown === "abort"` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9964979/315935)), but it could be differences in different version of jQuery. I would recommend you to set breakpoint inside of `loadError` and examine who calls it and whether jQuery really aborted.

The value `jqXHR.status === 0` can have another reason. Correspond to [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-status-attribute) specification such error will take place on network error. In an old version of jQuery (see [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617710/315935)) there was a bug and network errors were interpreted as "success". Later versions of jQuery fixed the bug and the callback `error` (and so `loadError`) will be called in case of network error. After analyzing of different cases which you have you can consider to modify the implementation of `loadError` which you use. For example you should include additional conditions like

```
loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (textStatus !== "abort" && errorThrown !== "abort") {
        // display alert
    }
}
```

or even test additionally for the case `jqXHR.status === 0` and `jqXHR.readyState === 0` (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate) too). In any way I'd recommend you to test the case carefully in one specific version of jQuery.

Comment: I can provide url which can used to reproduce the issue. jquery-1.9.1.min.js is used. Virtual scrolling is not used.